# Не сортировать товар в OpenCart

Tags: opencart

Есть такая проблема:
Если собирать товар, допустим в такой последовательности:

1. товар **A** размер 10
2. товар **B** размер 5
3. товар **A** размер 20

То в заказах будет сортированный вид, то есть такой:

1. товар **A** размер 10
2. товар **A** размер 20
3. товар **B** размер 5

А нужен такой же, как был "собран" изначальное, т.е. без какой-либо сортировки.
Можно ли это изменить где-то в настройках, к примеру. И можно ли вообще?

p.s.
Знания в OpenCart'е и backend'е - `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

system/library/cart/cart.php строку

```
$cart_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "'");
```

Заменить на:

```
$cart_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "' ORDER BY date_added ASC");
```

Решение для версии 2.x возможно и для 3.x подойдёт

Comment: `Version 2.1.0.2 (rs.1) (русская сборка)`, будет работать в ней?

Comment: Должно, попробуйте, откатиться всегда можно дело в пару сек